# Converting some objects

Tags: r, loops, vector, time-series, xts

Okay I have xts objects like

```
bid1, bid2, bid3, ..., bid30
```

They are intraday currency exchange rate data.
For example,

```
head(bid1)
```

Returns

```
                        ..2
2014-09-01 00:00:00 104.165
2014-09-01 00:00:01 104.352
2014-09-01 00:00:02 105.239
2014-09-01 00:00:03 104.891
2014-09-01 00:00:04 105.587
2014-09-01 00:00:05 105.028
```

and I would like to change them to vectors like

```
vbid1, vbid2, vbid3, ..., vbid30
```

I came up with coding like

```
i <- 1
for (i in 1:30)
{
 vbid[i] <- as.vector(bid[i])
 i <- i+1
}
```

But it didn't work.
It didn't return any errors or warnings, but when I check like

```
head(vbid1)
```

It says there is no object named 'vbid1'

Could anyone tell me good way to do that?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show some reproducible example.  Use `dput` to show `x1`, `x2` etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my question

Comment: Please check the posted solution.  `vask1` is not defined anywhere in the code showed

Comment: No problem.  Have you tested the solution

Comment: Actually I got an error Error in get(x[i]) : invalid first argument

Comment: Have you used `x <- paste0('bid', 1:n)` before running the `for` loop?

Comment: No I didn't let me try

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for(i in seq_along(x)){
assign(paste0('v',x[i]), as.vector(get(x[i])))
}

vbid1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
vbid2
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or use `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(mget(x), as.vector),
                   paste0('v',x)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
 <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

#### data

```
n <- 3
library(xts)
bid1 <- xts(1:5, order.by=seq(Sys.Date(),length.out=5, by='1 day'))
bid2 <- xts(6:10,order.by=seq(Sys.Date(),length.out=5, by='1 day'))
bid3 <- xts(1:15, order.by=seq(Sys.Date(),length.out=15, by='1 day'))
x <- paste0('bid', 1:n)
```